# Java REGEX appendReplacement() method not accepting a variable in the second argument

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string coming from a file:

```
{"comment":"<p>Some text with double quotes like (example, "$", "(", ")", etc.) here in a paragraph.</p>","replies":{"1":{"user":"Some User1","reply":"<p>This is another sample "data" with some double quotes.</p>","lastModified":"2017-04-12T15:03:06Z"},"2":{"user":"SomeUser2","reply":"<p>Yet another "data" with some more double quotes.</p>","lastModified":"2017-04-12T15:03:06Z"}}}
```

My goal is to escape the double quote characters within the HTML p (paragraph) tags and the way I am trying to do it is:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
      fis = new FileInputStream("PATH_TO_FILE");
      String data = IOUtils.toString(fis, "UTF-8");
      System.out.println("ORIGINAL: " + data + "-");

      Pattern pTagPattern = Pattern.compile("(<p>)(.*?)(</p>)");
      Matcher pTagMatcher = pTagPattern.matcher(data);

      String str ;
      Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
      int i = 1;
      while(pTagMatcher.find()) {
        map.put(i++, StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(pTagMatcher.group(2)));
      }

      Matcher pTagMatcher1 = pTagPattern.matcher(data);
      StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer();
      int j = 1;
      String str1;
      while(pTagMatcher1.find()) {
        str1 = map.get(j);
        pTagMatcher1.appendReplacement(sb1, str1); //<=== EXCEPTION HERE
        j++;
      }
      pTagMatcher1.appendTail(sb1);
      System.out.println("\nFINAL Text is: "  + sb1.toString());


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And when I run the above code, I get an exception as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Unknown Source)
    at my.project.package.util.Test.main(Test.java:54) (The line in the code above where I have "<=== EXCEPTION HERE")
```

The Exception is on the line:

`pTagMatcher1.appendReplacement(sb1, str1);`

Here, for the second parameter of `appendReplacement()` method, I am trying to use a variable instead of an actual literal string. When I use a literal string like "Sample Text", it works.

I am not very familiar with Java regex therefore would appreciate if somebody can point out what I am doing wrong here. Or would be great if somebody can suggest of another better way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is in the `str1` when the exception is thrown? The message says "Illegal group reference", which is in the forms like `\1` or `$1`...

Comment: I think the fix is  `pTagMatcher1.appendReplacement(sb1, Matcher.quoteReplacement(str1));`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - that's exactly what it was!! Thanks a lot for the quick response, you saved my day! I had tried that in the previous "while" loop but it was giving the same exception so didn't think about trying it again after adding the second "while" loop. If you reply again with your suggestion as an answer instead of a comment here, I will mark it as correct answer! :) Thanks again for your timely help!